# Hi, I have problem with redirecting to a route after sending email form in laravel

Tags: laravel, redirect

This is my contact form:

```xml
<form class="nk-form-submit" action="{{ route('contactPost', app()->getLocale()) }}" method="post">
  {{ csrf_field() }}
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="field-item animated" data-animate="fadeInUp" data-delay="0.8">
        <label class="field-label ttu" style="color: #1b1f25">{{__('contact.name.h')}}</label>
        <div class="field-wrap">
          <input name="name" placeholder="{{__('contact.name.t')}}" type="text" class="input-bordered required" style="color: #1b1f25">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="field-item animated" data-animate="fadeInUp" data-delay="0.9">
        <label class="field-label ttu" style="color: #1b1f25">{{__('contact.email.h')}}</label>
        <div class="field-wrap">
          <input name="email" placeholder="{{__('contact.email.t')}}" type="email" class="input-bordered required email" style="color: #1b1f25">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="field-item animated" data-animate="fadeInUp" data-delay="1.0">
    <label class="field-label ttu" style="color: #1b1f25">{{__('contact.message.h')}}</label>
    <div class="field-wrap">
      <textarea name="text" placeholder="{{__('contact.message.t')}}" type="text" class="input-bordered input-textarea required" style="color: #1b1f25"></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
  <input type="text" class="d-none" name="form-anti-honeypot" value="">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-5 text-right animated" data-animate="fadeInUp" data-delay="1.1">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-round btn-secondary"><span style="font-weight: bold">{{__('contact.b1')}}</span></button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-7 order-sm-first">
      <div class="form-results">
        @include('template._partials._alert')
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Here are the handling Controller functions:

```php
public function contactPost(Request $request, $locale) 
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'name' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'text' => 'required'
    ]);

    Mail::send('email', [
        'name' => $request->get('name'),
        'email' => $request->get('email'),
        'text' => $request->get('text')
    ], function ($message) {
        $message->to('info@wexopay.com')->subject('Wexo Token Contact Mail');
    });

    return redirect()->route('contactSuccess', $locale);
}

public function contactSuccess()
{
    return view('contact');
}
```

When I inspect the problem in my browser you can clearly see that the method has successfully returned the view:
[Inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nIvDi.png)

My web.php file:

```php
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
    
Route::get('/', function () { return redirect('/en/defi'); });
    
Route::group(['prefix' => '{language}'], function () {

    Route::get('/defi', ['as' => 'web.home', 'uses' => 'PagesController@index']);
    Route::get('/contact', ['as' => 'contactSuccess', 'uses' => 'PagesController@contactSuccess']);
    Route::post('/defi', ['as' => 'contactPost', 'uses' => 'PagesController@contactPost']);
    
});
```

Problem is, I don't get redirected. Can anyone help me please? I was also trying to send flash message and simply refresh the page.

Comment: Welcome to SO ... please do not put up pictures of code, code is text and it belongs in your question as text in a code block ... thank you

Comment: xhr is a ajax request, are you using ajax call?

Comment: Can you post the `contactSuccess` method as well?

Comment: Here is the contactSuccess method: public function contactSuccess() {
        return view('contact');
    }

Comment: do you get redirected correctly if you put `return view('contact')` instead of `return redirect()...` ?

Comment: I tried every method of redirecting even returning the view, redirect()->to(), redirect()->back(), Redirect::...u name it

Comment: What about this: `return redirect()->route('contactSuccess', ['language' => $locale]);` ?

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry, finally found what was the problem.
I used a package that I bought for this project and the form elemnt had a class that identified it will be handled by package in-built functions in .js files.
I solved the problem by removing the class from html element.
Thanks for your help guys.